# Cloudant search index limit 200

Tags: python, cloudant

I know that the results of query *search index* have a limit of 200 rows.

Exist any way to view all docs matches?

I'm write in Python with Python Cloudant API and I need all rows for *search* using *Search Index*.

I want to know if I can do this using *Search Index* before using views or querys directly.

The result of query all data is:

{
"total_rows":1239,
"bookmark":"g1AAAAJveJzLYWBg4MhgTmHQTElKzi9KdUhJMtRLytVNTtYtLdYtzi8tydA1MNRLzskvTUnMK9HLSy3JAWphSmRIkv___39WBpOb_QcGMEhkRjXHnBhzkhSAZJI9ulFMIKO0EE4iyk1JDiCz4gmZZUCUWQkgs-qxmkViUOWxgLQ2ACmgafPxGUdUiEGMWwAxbj_loQYx7wDEvPuUhxzEvAcQ89BCLwsAMoq9cQ",
"rows":[...]
}

And the length of *"rows"* is defined by *limit* parameter, but this max limit is 200.

How can I see all rows of my query?.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to page through the search results 200 at a time. This is pretty straightforward using the bookmark in the response. If you post your design document here and some sample data documents I could help more.

Comment: I update the question, the Search index Analyzer is Simple and type is Standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you got your response with the following query:

`https://$ACCOUNT.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/_design/$DDOC/_search/$INDEX_NAME?limit=200`

You would get the next 200 rows with this query:

`https://$ACCOUNT.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/_design/$DDOC/_search/$INDEX_NAME?limit=200&bookmark="g1AAAAJveJzLYWBg4MhgTmHQTElKzi9KdUhJMtRLytVNTtYtLdYtzi8tydA1MNRLzskvTUnMK9HLSy3JAWphSmRIkv___39WBpOb_QcGMEhkRjXHnBhzkhSAZJI9ulFMIKO0EE4iyk1JDiCz4gmZZUCUWQkgs-qxmkViUOWxgLQ2ACmgafPxGUdUiEGMWwAxbj_loQYx7wDEvPuUhxzEvAcQ89BCLwsAMoq9cQ"`

To get all the documents for your query, write a function that recursively queries the database with the bookmark value coming from the previous response each time. Do this until your response has less than 200 documents, which is how you know you're done.

Full documentation on querying a Cloudant search index is here:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#queries

Comment: {
error: "bad_request",
reason: "Invalid bookmark parameter supplied"
}